# Media images in production vanishes for some time after Impex import

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

Images in homepage and search result pages are missing for some time, this happens after performing `Impex import` for products after making some changes in media files. The product details page works fine by showing the updated images after synchronization from staged to the online catalog.

Interestingly this issue will be solved after some time makes it difficult to debug.

Comment: Could you please add also the varnish config? Because this sounds like a varnish cache problem. Are you caching homepage?

Comment: Think about cache as @HybrisFreelance said.

Comment: @HybrisFreelance: am not caching it.still how this problem can occur in search result?

Comment: What kind of media storage/url strategy are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to the Solr indexing after synchronization. after impex import and synchronization with online cataloge,the media URL will get updated.Since the Product details page fetch image url's from database,it will show up.but the respective images in home page and search pages are taken from solr and that is not valid anymore because the cron job to update sold index not yet completed.

The solution is to replace the image  URL which is suppose to be shown in search page as well as in the home page contained in product data to the updated one  from DB using modelservice().save(productData) using populator.